# Parse JSON data to label

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
 reponsedata = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    NSString *loc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://advantixcrm.com/prj/mitech/index.php/api/appconfig/Mg"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loc]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (reponsedata)
    {

        NSDictionary *Dictionarydetails = [NSJSONSerialization
                                           JSONObjectWithData:reponsedata
                                           options:kNilOptions
                                           error:nil];
        NSLog(@"The return data is: %@",Dictionarydetails);

        NSMutableDictionary *tempdict = [Dictionarydetails valueForKey:@"AppConfig"];
        array=[tempdict valueForKey:@"RestInfo"];

        NSLog(@"the result  are %@",array);
        NSLog(@"the result count is are %d",[array count]);


        NSDictionary *classDict  = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

        for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
            //arr = [Class_location objectForKey:@"class_image"];
            classDict =[array objectAtIndex:i];
            // NSLog(@"the  dict Values are  are: %@",classDict);
            NSMutableArray  *dict1 =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            dict1 =[classDict valueForKey:@"RestInfo"];
            NSLog(@"the result :%@",dict1);

            lb1.text =[classDict valueForKey:@"restaurant_location"];
            lbl2.text = [classDict valueForKey:@"restaurant_name"];
            lbl3.text = [classDict valueForKey:@"contact_name"];

        }
    }
}
```

the problem was I can't get those value to label
well I got my response from server

Comment: post your response data

Comment: can u post what is in your dict1 and classDict

Comment: Please post your response data and desired value

Comment: dictionarydetails=(_NSCFDictionary *) 3key/value pairs tempdict=(_NSCFDictionary *) 6key/value pairs array=(NSconcreteMutabledata*)nil

Comment: hey try Retro code it correct

Comment: did you got your result

Comment: dic1 was mutable array classdic NSdictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//your answer for the script this code check the ans in console, i am waiting for your response


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://advantixcrm.com/prj/mitech/index.php/api/appconfig/Mg"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

 NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSArray *array=[jsonArray objectForKey:@"RestInfo"];

for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"the restrunt==%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"restaurant_location"]);
    NSLog(@"the resname==%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"restaurant_name"]);
    NSLog(@"the resname==%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"contact_name"]);

}

}
```

**Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()
 var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://advantixcrm.com/prj/mitech/index.php/api/appconfig/Mg")!)
 request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
request.setValue("application/json;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
NSError * err
NSURLResponse * response
var responseData: NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: response!, error: err!)
var jsonArray: [NSObject : AnyObject] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers, error: err!)
var array: [AnyObject] = (jsonArray["RestInfo"] as! [AnyObject])
for var i = 0; i < array.count; i++ {
    NSLog("the restrunt==%@", (array[i]["restaurant_location"] as! String))
    NSLog("the resname==%@", (array[i]["restaurant_name"] as! String))
    NSLog("the resname==%@", (array[i]["contact_name"] as! String))
 }
}
```

Comment: have u try the above coding, its wok fine for u

Comment: simple remove the nslog  and assign the NSString in instance, 2. declare the one global mutable array, 3. finally [mutablearay addobject:nsstringvalue], 4. show the mutable array in tableview, just like cell.textlabel.text=[mutablearray objectatindex:indexpath.row];

Comment: sorry will u please explain detail

Comment: ok i got the table view but how can i bring it multiple value

Comment: use nsmutablearray just like [nsmutablearray arraywitharray:yourarrayname]; and pass the nsmutable array to the table view

Comment: here i got only one location but i need how much location there that i need

Answer (score 1):

Use This:

```
NSError *err= nil;
NSArray* arrayDetails= [NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData:reponsedata
                                   options:kNilOptions
                                   error:&err];
[arrayDetails enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    if([obj objectForKey:@"event_date"] isEqualTo:@"myDate")
    {
         lb1.text =[obj objectForKey:@"restaurant_location"];
            lbl2.text = [obj objectForKey:@"restaurant_name"];
            lbl3.text = [obj objectForKey:@"contact_name"];
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSArray *arrayDetails = [NSJSONSerialization
                                   JSONObjectWithData:reponsedata
                                   options:kNilOptions
                                   error:nil];
    for(NSDictionary* dict in arrayDetails) {
     lb1.text  = dict[@"RestInfo"][@"restaurant_location"];
     lbl2.text = dict[@"RestInfo"][@"restaurant_name"];
     lbl3.text = dict[@"RestInfo"][@"contact_name"];
    }
```

This will do the needful I think

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your json response closely, you will find the following structure,

[image]

Dictionary **-> RestInfo** Array **->** Required Dictionary

So your parser code should be as below,

```
NSDictionary *rootDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:reponsedata
                                                   options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:nil];

NSArray *restInfoArray = [rootDictionary valueForKey:@"RestInfo"];
for (NSDictionary *dict in rootDictionary) {
    lbl1.text = [dict valueForKey:@"restaurant_name"];
    lbl2.text = [dict valueForKey:@"restaurant_location"];
    lbl3.text = [dict valueForKey:@"contact_name"];
}
```

Please note that in case the `RestInfo` array returns multiple dictionaries, the `lbl1`, `lbl2` and `lbl3` will show text for the last dictionary keys. You need to have appropriate UI to handle such scenario.

Hope that helps!